# Laravel 4.2.11 artisan tinker error message

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to put information of an user account by the tinker command and i have this error message:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/var/www/html/ecommerce$ php artisan tinker
[1] > dd(Auth::attempt([
[1] *> "email"=>adeckow@yahoo.com
[1] *>  "password"=>$2y$10$0znNZbRi7q69fbheyQAGnOvq5gFMbxDBnUbpr1bUYOXGER9RuNU9e]));
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting ']' in /var/www/html/ecommerce/vendor/d11wtq/boris/lib/Boris/EvalWorker.php(133) : eval()'d code on line 2
// false
```

i've tried with 'at', and i don't know if it's possible to put the encrypted password. I'm following this tutorial but isn't clear at all: 
https://medium.com/laravel-4/laravel-4-e-commerce-c5afca925f28

UPDATED!

i've already solved the problem and i put a password that is not hashed, but it still returns bool(false)

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need to put your values in quotes: `"email" => 'adeckow@yahoo.com'`, and there's a comma missing between them. So the correct array passed to `Auth::atempt()` should be `['email' => 'adeckow@yahoo.com', 'password' => '$2y$10$0znNZbR...']`

Comment: Hey! thank you! it really worked, i get "bool(false)" message, i need to get "true"... i will search more info. Thank you again!

Comment: The password sent to `attempt` should not be hashed.

Comment: Oh! thank you! i thought that, but the Faker generates users with encrypted passwords, i will search more info.